# NetBSD: "make install" with bsd.*.mk scripts: How to automatically create non-existing directories

Tags: makefile, installation, mkdir, netbsd

On a NetBSD system I have a makefile with no install target. Included makefiles are

```
bsd.xconf.mk
bsd.prog.mk
bsd.xorg.mk
```

The following relevant variables are set

```
PROG
BINDIR
MANDIR
MAN
```

When I type

```
make install
```

PROG is installed in BINDIR and files in MAN are installed in MANDIR.
But if BINDIR or MANDIR do not exist they are not created.

What do I need to specify in the Makefile for creating non-existing directories?
(Of course writing a install target would work but I would like to use the automatism from the .mk scripts.)

I tried e.g. to set variables

```
INSTALL_MAN_DIR
INSTALLATION_DIRS
```

but nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mayby you should install it manually.

```
PROG = xxxxx
DESTDIR = /usr/local/test/make
BINDIR = /bin

include bsd.prog.mk

beforeinstall:
    ${INSTALL} -d $(DESTDIR)$(BINDIR)
```